# Introductory Computer Science assignments

Tags: java, computer-science, variable-assignment

I will be teaching my first university level Computer Science course this summer, and I'm currently working on coming up with ideas for fun assignments that the students will complete.  The course is the second in the program, covering analysis of algorithms and basic data structures such as stacks, queues, lists, trees, etc.

I have a number of ideas that I can run with (creating music with Markov chains, Twitter client, etc.), but am always looking for new ideas that would be interesting/fun for the students -- after all, it is easiest to become/remain engaged in the course material when one is having fun.  I am looking for ideas on interessting first-year level assignments that you or others may have completed in the past.

Before anyone suggests it, yes I know about Nifty Assignments, and have checked it out.  Just soliciting any other ideas that you might have.  We all remember certain assignments from university that were particularly fun to work on.  These are the experiences I am ideally seeking.

Comment: Look at my question from the same area, maybe you'll find something useful for you there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318770/impressive-examples-in-java

Answer (score 4):

The trouble with "fun" assignments is that they often turn out to be more work for students than you intended them to be.  Especially students with poor English and students who leave the assignments to the last minute.  [And then turn up on SO with "please do my homework" questions.]  A lot of them are going to have difficulty with any assignments you set, but you don't need the aggravation of a bunch of students complaining about the exercises being too hard, or not being covered in your lecture notes.

My advice (from experience) is to try to keep the amount of background knowledge and "challenge" of marked programming assignments low.

Setting interesting problems for optional exercises is a reasonable idea, though it is important to warn students NOT to spend time on them at the expense of other more important work.

Comment: I definitely agree, and am looking to keep assignments short and relatively simple -- but hopefully sweet as well. :)  I have had the opportunity to create a few assignments in the past for the same course (in a teaching assistant role).  Some worked well, and indeed some ended up being just as you described -- fun and interesting, but too long and complicated for the students.  Nevertheless, I am hoping to find a few gems that might just be simple enough to understand and complete, while still being fun.  Certainly though, I respect your answer and will take strides to keep things simple.

Comment: Students with poor English and students who leave the assignments to the last minutes should have been filtered long before reaching the university level. Still being reasonable with "fun" level will give you less hassle when checking the assignments and interacting with students.

Comment: @Anonymous - unfortunately, that is not the way it really works.

Comment: I downvoted this because you're implying there is no such thing as a fun assignment - that everything designed to be fun turns into a depressing chore. This is simply not true. Fun and engagement has very little correlation with something being too challenging. I also don't think that something being fun negatively impacts on those who leave things late or have poor English skills. Regardless, if either of those things is negatively effecting a student then they are not suited to the course in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

[SICP](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-4.html#%_toc_start) has some very nice assignments.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using the following pages as an inspiration:

- [Nifty Assignments](http://nifty.stanford.edu/)
- [Creative Programming Assignments](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/introcs/assignments/) - there are several (sub)sections (introduction to CS, introduction to programming.

You can also use the tasks from contests ([example](http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8)), but this will most likely require some work on your side - to assure fairness in distributing the assignments (some might be tricky, and not focused on the things you've mentioned).

Answer (score 1):

package assignment01; /* Make sure this class is in package assignment01. */

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

/**
 * This class is a collection of methods that perform various mathematical functions. The methods are all static. This
 * class is part of assignment #1.
 * 
 * @author ..........
 * @version jun 15 2010
 */
public class MathLibrary
{

```
/**
 * Computes and returns the mean (average) of the numbers in the list.
 * 
 * If the input list is empty, the returned mean is 0.0. If the list contains illegal values, the behavior of this
 * method is undefined.
 * 
 * @param list
 *            an ArrayList of double values
 * @return the mean of the values in the list
 */
public static double mean (ArrayList<Double> list)
{
    // Variables

    Double sum = 0.0;
    int arraySize = 0;

    // Check for empty list

    if ( list.size()== 0 )
        return 0.0;

    // Take sum

    arraySize = list.size();
    for( int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++ )
    {

        // Check for null Double

        if( list.get(i) == null )
        {
            System.out.println("Mean Function: Array has null element at index: " + i + ".");
            return -1.0;
        }

        // Add element

        sum += list.get(i);
    }

    // Return average of results

    return (sum / arraySize);
  }

/**
 * Computes and returns the median value of the numbers in the list. If the list has an odd number of elements, the
 * exact median value is returned. If the list has an even number of elements, the average of the middle two
 * elements is returned.
 * 
 * If the input list is empty, the returned mean is 0.0. If the list contains illegal values, the behavior of this
 * method is undefined.
 * 
 * The order of the elements in the input array may be changed by this method.
 * 
 * @param arr
 *            an array of double values
 * @return the median of the values in the list
 */
public static double median (double[] arr)
{
     // Variables

    double arraySize = 0;
    double arrayMedian = 0.0;
    double temp = 0.0;
    boolean unsorted = true;

    // Check for empty array

    arraySize = arr.length;
    if (arraySize == 0.0)
        return 0.0;

    // Sort array

    while(unsorted)
    {
        unsorted = false;
        for( int i=0; i < arraySize - 1; i++)
        {
            if( arr[i] > arr[i+1] )
            {
                unsorted = true;
                temp = arr[i + 1];
                arr[i+1] = arr[i];
                arr[i] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    // Find median

    if((arraySize % 2) == 0) 
    {
        // Take average of two middle array indicies 

        arrayMedian = (arr[(int) (arraySize/2.0 - 0.5)] + arr[(int) (arraySize/2.0 + 0.5)]) / 2.0;
    } else {
        arrayMedian = arr[(int) (arraySize/2.0)];
    }


    return arrayMedian;
  }

/**
 * Computes and returns the largest integer that divides (without remainder) both of the input integers (the
 * greatest common divisor).
 * 
 * If either of the input integers is not positive, this method returns -1.
 * 
 * @param a
 *            any positive integer
 * @param b
 *            any positive integer
 * @return the greatest common divisor of a and b
 */
public static int gcd (int a, int b)
{
  int gcd = 1;
  int minimum;

  // Check for (a || b) < 0

  if ((a < 0) || (b < 0))
      return -1;
  if ((a == 0) || (b == 0))
      return 0;

  // Compute half the minimum(a,b)

  minimum = Math.min(a,b);

  // For each number below half the minimum of the two check for divisibility

  for( int i = 1; i <= minimum; i++ ) // zero case is already accounted for
  {
      // Check for divisibility

      if(((a % i) == 0) && ((b % i) == 0))
      {
         gcd = i; 
      }
  }

     return gcd;
 }

/**
 * Computes and returns the smallest integer that can be divided by (without remainder) both of the input integers
 * (the least common multiple).
 * 
 * 
 * If either of the input integers is not positive, this method returns -1. If the least common multiple exceeds the
 * maximum possible integer value, the behavior of this method is undefined.
 * 
 * @param a
 *            any positive integer
 * @param b
 *            any positive integer
 * @return the least common multiple of a and b
 */
public static int lcm (int a, int b)
{
    // Variables

    int lcm = 0;

    // Check for negative numbers

    if((a < 0) || (b < 0))
        return -1;

    // Use gcd to get lcm

    lcm = (a * b) / gcd(a,b);

    return lcm;
  }

/**
 * Given a number n, this method computes and returns the smallest prime number larger than n.
 * 
 * If the input integer is not positive, this method returns 2. If the next prime number exceeds the maximum
 * possible integer value, the behavior of this method is undefined.
 * 
 * @param n
 *            an integer
 * @return the smallest prime number larger than n
 */
private static boolean isPrime(int n)

{

if( n == 2 || n == 3 )
{
  return true;
}

if( n == 1 || n % 2 == 0 )
{
  return false;
}
for( int i = 3; i * i <= n; i += 2 )

if( n % i == 0 )
{
  return false;
}


return true;

}

public static int nextPrime(int n)
{
  if (n<0)
{
  return 2; //if n is not positive.
}
  int value = n;
  if (n == 2)
   value = 3; //finds the next prime number.
  else
  {
    do
    {
      value += 1;
    } while (!isPrime(value));
  }
  return value; //displays the next prime number.
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

One thing to consider, maybe not for the first programming course the students do, but later on, is to hand them back code from previous assignments (their own or someone else's) for fixing. THis works better if you pick incorrect submissions, ideally with subtle flaws.

A similar idea is to have a sequence of labs, using the (successfully completed) code from the previous lab as a starting-point. When I did the introductory programming course (PINK - programming in incremental systems) at LiU, lo so many years ago, there was one segment of teh lab work that (essentially) boiled down to implementing a calendar, using abstract types and accessors, then changing the implementation of the abstract type afterwards. Quite valuable for illustrating the need of providing a good interface you don't need to side-step, if nothing else (from memory, I ended up spending a day or two pondering the "change implementation", then 15-20 minutes actually changing my abstract data types, since I'd done the hard work up front and just needed to convince myself of this).

Answer (score 0):

Pig Latin.

Have your students write code that translates a text stream from English to Pig Latin.  [The rules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pig_Latin) are fairly simple, but they will require some interesting special cases, especially when it comes to punctuation and capitalization, requiring them to write a basic scanner/tokenizer.

With a typical sentence like this:

```
Quietly, Anne walked into the forest.
```

You should get this:

```
ietly-quay, Anne-ay alked-way into-ay e-thay orest-fay.
```

but you are likely to get:

```
uietly,-Qay Anne-ay alked-way into-ay e-thay orest.-fay
```

which has misplaced punctuation, improperly placed Qu and incorrect capitalization.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of ideas that I've found to resonate with students:

1. Fractal art--an excellent way to teach recursion because students can visualize the process (ex. sierpinski triangle, [L-systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-system) for ambitious students).  You can see some pretty impressive graphics generated with context-free grammars over at [context free art](http://www.contextfreeart.org/).
2. Image manipulation--teach functional programming by mapping pixel manipulation functions across an image (ex. swap color channels, Gaussian blur, manipulate hue); this is somewhat simpler than the typical [syntax tree-based generative art](http://nifty.stanford.edu/2009/stone-random-art/) assignments.

The hardest part about teaching introductory-level computer science classes is the disparity in programming ability across the typical class.  So, if you can create assignments that can be simple enough for the less capable students and easily extended (through extra credit for example) to more complex problems for advanced students, then that is ideal in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

One task I remember fondly when I think back to my early days at university was a task designed to teach us about GUIs. We were asked to implement a web browser.

The actual display of web content was not particularly important - we were encouraged to use a Swing web view - it was more about the functionality which supported this:

- a URL bar
- history
- forward and back
- setting a home page
- maintaining bookmarks/favourites
- tabbed browsing
- etc

The assignment gave you free rein to choose any combination of these, provided you did at least a set number. This allowed the really keen people to implement absolutely all of the features if they wanted, and allowed anyone who was more rushed to simply implement the minimum.

There were a few more tasks which were structured in a similar way over the years and they always went down well. You'd be surprised how often the students will go the extra mile and do more than is required.

---

As a general rule of thumb, the things myself and my coursemates seemed to find the most engaging were more visual: OpenGL, GUIs, websites etc. Any command-line-based programs weren't as fun.

Perhaps as you're focusing on algorithms it could be a good idea to get students to visualise sorting/searching algorithms. In addition to teaching them about a graphics framework, it would help visualise the algorithm and cement their understanding of it. You could do a similar thing with custom implementations of data structures.

The key to this would be finding a graphics framework that are reasonably intuitive, well-documented, well-used and well-supported. There was nothing more frustrating than assignments which forced us to use technologies that no one in the real world actually uses. You do not want to make learning this technology the hardest part of the task.

I don't think it's necessarily a bad thing that you'll be teaching them to use a framework that may be considered outside the scope of the module: learning how to use new frameworks and libraries is a skill in itself which needs to be developed if you're to be an effective software developer and universities do not seem to teach this explicitly.